# Pandas not able to open a csv file overnight

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am building a script that generates a csv file with pandas, but i'm trying to make it so if the file already exists in the designated path, the script will only append the new info into the existing file, while if the file doesn't exist, it will create a new one.

My code right now is like this:

```
#Trying to find the file in the designated path and then appending the new info

try:
   pd.read_csv('file.csv', encoding = 'ANSI')
   info.to_csv('file.csv', index = False, header = None, sep = ';', encoding = 'ANSI', decimal = ',', mode = 'a')

#Creating a new file into the existing path if it doesn't exist

except IOError:
   info.to_csv('file.csv',  index = False, sep = ';', encoding = 'ANSI', decimal = ',', header = True)
```

This works fine during the day, but when I try to run the script the next day, the `pd.read_csv()` encounters the following error:

*ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 10, saw 2*

I've read that one way to resolve this is by adding the parameter `error_bad_lines = False`, but this results in an exponentially slower computational time. The verbose in this case shows that almost every line of the .csv file has some extra *\n* in it.

Is there some other way to tackle this file appending/creating problem?

I need to be able to open this file in excel to check the infos inside. Should I just try to create an .xlsx file instead of a .csv?

Comment: The error message is in English. "Expected 1 fields in line 10, saw 2". What does your csv file look like? It looks like there's only one column. Is that right? That is. The first 9 lines do not contain any `;` separators.

Comment: Why are you not using the same arguments for decimal and sep in `read_csv` as you use in `to_csv`?

Comment: add more information about the file and it's structure, the problem maybe in the data you want to append to the existing file

Comment: when checking for whether a file exists or not try using a module that interacts with your os. `from pathlib import Path`;`if Path('path_to_csv').is_file():`....

Answer (score 1):

Use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to check if the file already [exists](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.exists). If you really want to load the whole file (only to check if it exists) you would need to use the same parameters as in the `pd.to_csv` settings. But the latter is computationally very expensive for a simple check so I would recommend to use `pathlib`.

The default separator in `pd.read_csv` is `,` (which is your decimal separator) so the error is probably from trying to read the file with the wrong delimiter (more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)).

Possible solution:

```py
from pathlib import Path

if Path('file.csv').exists():
    info.to_csv('file.csv', index = False, header = None, sep = ';', encoding = 'ANSI', decimal = ',', mode = 'a')
else:
    info.to_csv('file.csv',  index = False, sep = ';', encoding = 'ANSI', decimal = ',', header = True)
```